# Does deleting rows from a table distrupts indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know that if we delete some rows (I am talking for sql server) from a table which has some indexes (clustered or non-clustered, for both situation) can give any damage to indexes or not? What happens to indexes when we delete rows? Which one is better for performance, deleting rows from a table after processing them, or mark up them as processed (When we will need to reuse them like 20 times more). Thanks for the answers.

Comment: When ever data is changed in a column that has an index, the index is also updated. So, a `DELETE` statement will mean that all the indexes on the table will need to be updated, as will an `INSERT`. With an `UPDATE`, however, then only the indexes on the column(s) affected will need an update. As for the latter, that is completely up to your business requirement. If you need a history; then deleting seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We need to update the indexes right? Sql server does not update them automatically.

Comment: They will be updated automatically, but they may become fragmented over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "damage".  When you delete rows from the table, the index entries need to be deleted as well.  This does not "damage" the index per se.  At least, the index continues to be useful.

If you have lots of deletes, updates, and inserts, then over time the index will be fragmented.  This does affect performance.  At some point it becomes useful to re-build the index for performance purposes.  You can read about this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes).

I would not worry about rebuilding the indexes because of a handful of deletes.  It takes a bit of work to really fragment an index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we do delete operation only, will it cause the fragmentation again? I think it does not but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is YES.
Index is created on data in the tables and in short if data is deleted from the tables then the levels of fragmentation rise. 
Rise in fragmentation levels effects the data retrieval in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.